# How to speed up julia script launch time

Tags: julia

I've wrote a script to plot daily data in Julia, but I found it run slow. Seems no ideal method to speed it up.

for example foo.jl

```
#!/bin/bash
#=
exec julia -O0 --compile=min "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" "$@"
=#

using UnicodePlots, CSV, DataFrames, Chain, Dates
...
```

I wish if first time I run 'foo.jl a.csv b.csv", it may takes time to compile/load (10 seconds).
And the 2nd time I run it, it can skip the compile process.(It should be around 3 seconds).

Is it possible now? I'm use version 1.8.3.
Or, can I setup those packages which I used as default required compiled every time I launch julia to speed it up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Julia seems to be very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73599900/julia-seems-to-be-very-slow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a system image and give this a parameter each time when starting Julia:

```
using PackageCompiler
create_sysimage(["UnicodePlots, CSV, DataFrames, Chain"], sysimage_path="sys_foo.so", precompile_execution_file="script_with_your_typical_workflow.jl")
```

After this is done you will need to run your code as:

```
julia --sysimage sys_foo.so foo.jl
```

For more information see this thread:
[Julia seems to be very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73599900/julia-seems-to-be-very-slow)

Comment: I change to `["UnicodePlots", "CSV", "DataFrames", "Chain"]` The 'Dates' require to removed, maybe already in system image. And it generated.

Comment: BTW, this method will stick the packages' version according to the document. So, required re-compile when you updated the packages' version.

Comment: yes - `Dates` should be ommited - my fault :) and unfortunately you will need to recompile when anything changes

Answer (score 4):

While I believe Przemyslaw's answer is the best advise at this point, I'd like to add two points:

- Another option is to use the [`DaemonMode.jl`](https://github.com/dmolina/DaemonMode.jl) package, which implements a client/server model to keep compiled code in memory.
- Also, the "time to first X" latency problem has been a high priority for the core language devs for a long time, and it appears at the time of writing that we might start to see material improvements in Julia versions 1.9 and 1.10 towards native code caching. A variety of other avenues for addressing the issues are being pursued more or less actively in parallel, so if you are a reader from 2023 or later building sysimages might not be required any longer.

Comment: I saw a graph somewhere with 1.9 compiler improvements - they look Huge indeed :)  The Deamon mode looks like something quite useful - have you been testing this in more kind of a production environment (eg. when this needs to run for a week or so between restarts)?

Comment: I've never really used it other than to see how it works, but I've seen a few positive testimonials on the Julia Community so it seemed worth mentioning.