# Why does my julia plot pane show nothing in VS Code?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

[image]
I both using Julia 1.6 and Julia 1.9. both can't plot anything, or sometimes give a shift shrinkle plots.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi user22418091! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include any code you have thanks :-)

Comment: I think its not the code mistake because I tried in julia and it runs well. but in vscode, it finish plot but give none plot

Comment: that's not the point. Please share your code. You could be using a particular library or a version of a library which is bad, or a function which is bad with something else in vscode. without seeing your code it's impossible to say

Comment: using Plots

A=[1,7,9,2]
B=[1,4,4,7]
plot(A,B)
just for this small snippet it always give nothing, I've tried julia in 1.9 and 1.6 and both doesnt work

Comment: is there anything else i can provide to make it clear, sy i'm freshman in julia and vscode, its hard for me to get the point

Comment: Provide your code, the Julia packages+environment you're using, and your VSCode setup if possible

Comment: Occasionally I have seen this. Sometimes changing the backend helps. Also sometimes, if you use display() as in plt = plot(A,B); display(plt), it may overcome the issue with VS code noticing a plot is generated.

Comment: If you haven't seen it already: Here is a nice answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73599180/plot-not-showing-in-julia). In short: calling `display(p)` after the last `plot!`call might help.